# Android turn-by-turn navigation app with traffic that does not require Google Location Services

Tags: android, navigation

I'm looking for recommendations for an Android navigation app with the following required features:

1. Does not use Google Location Services (strictly uses the GPS for location data, or uses another location service that does not require root privileges to install)
2. Provides voice turn-by-turn directions
3. Provides real-time US traffic data, and takes traffic into account when routing and re-routing
4. Is [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) or costs no more (including maps) than a good cup of coffee
5. Does not require a rooted device

Here are some optional features that would be nice, but are *not* requirements:

1. In the voice turn-by-turn directions, state the street name (ex. "Turn right on Elm Street")
2. Can download maps for offline use
3. Prefer no recurring charges

(Please indicate which optional features your recommendation includes.)

Comment: Related, and with answers (at least partially) fitting here: [Offline map browser on Android with offline search](/q/82/185) // [App for Android that reads Open Street Map data but can be used as a GPS or for Directions](/q/101/185) // [Android navigation app that can download entire US region offline](/q/39380/185) // [Looking for on-road offline GPS/Nav software on Android](/q/18345/185)

Comment: Hopefully someone has experience with (or knowledge of) an app that meets all the above requirements.

Comment: I cannot tell about US-specific things (requirement #3) – but *Locus* (mentioned in answers to most of the linked question) should fit the rest. Depending on where you're used to get your coffee, that is. Besides, an alternative to widen the number of candidates is to use *microG* – which would mean no Google location at all for any app :)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks Izzy.  I'm not seeing any mention of ***traffic*** for Locus.  Am I missing something?  BTW, I've always been curious about *microG*... but it requires completely removing Google Play Services.  Although I like that idea, I'm concerned it will limit quite a bit of functionality.

Comment: Traffic: Not sure, never needed that. Be welcome to check with my [Locus Maps Resources](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_locus). *microG:* Why? It replaces them. Do you think you will miss what it doesn't replace (ads, analytics and other spying stuff)? Apart from which, if you only care for location and really want to stick with the GBloat: check *UnifiedNLP* (at F-Droid, chose the variant for devices *with GApps).* That part of *microG Core* is available stand-alone, too (via F-Droid), and would only serve location.

Comment: Have you tried Sygic, I think its the closest candidate I can think of, and that I use

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Yes, it's quite good.  The downside is that it is very expensive.  So I only used it during the trial period.

Comment: Aww I Heard HereWeGo (formerly HereMaps) can do a similar job and is free, don't if it suits your needs though? +1 This question is interesting